# TypeError: state is not iterable on react with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tried to make a simple list with redux and react. But when I click on the button to add a bookmark product to the bookmarks list I got an error "TypeError: state.bookmarks is not iterable
"

Here is my code

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  bookmarks: [],
};

const productReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
 case ADD_TO_BOOKMARK:
      return {
        ...state,
        bookmarks: [...state.bookmarks, action.payload],
      };
  default:
      return state;
}
```

actions

```
export const REMOVE_BOOKMARK = "REMOVE_BOOKMARK";
export const addToBookmarks = (product) => ({
  type: ADD_TO_BOOKMARK,
  payload: product,
});
```

Product.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { HeartIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { AddItem, addToBookmarks, toggleHidden } from "../redux/actions";
import { CustomButton } from "../Components";

const MAX_LENGTH_TITLE = 20;
const MAX_LENGTH_DESCRIPTION = 50;

const Product = ({ product, addToBookmarks, toggleHidden }) => {
  const { title, category, description, image, price } = product || {};
  const [bookmark, setBookmark] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
       .....
        ....
      <HeartIcon
        className={`absolute top-2 right-4 w-8 cursor-pointer ${
          bookmark ? "text-yellow-500" : "text-gray-500"
        }`}
        onClick={() => {
               addToBookmarks(product); 
               setBookmark(!bookmark);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addToBookmarks: (product) => dispatch(addToBookmarks(product)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Product);
```

BookmarksPage.jsx
**Here I got the error when I log bookmarks **

```
   .... 
   ..... 
    const Bookmarks = ({ bookmarks }) => {
      console.log(bookmarks);
      return (
        <div>
          {bookmarks.map((product) => {
            return <h1>{product.title}</h1>;
          })}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
      bookmarks: selectBookmarksProducts,
    });
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Bookmarks);
```

Comment: My guess is that your bookmarks are not an array anymore somewhere. Try to print the bookmarks to the console and look what type it is right before the error message.

Comment: I tried that and I got an object but I don't why while I set an initialState ( bookmarks : [ ] ) and I dispatch an action  addToBookmarks(product) while product is an object

Comment: Could you please add console.log(state.bookmarks) after case ADD_TO_BOOKMARK:

Comment: @Tatiana I got this error Uncaught TypeError: state.bookmarks is not iterable

Comment: And if just console.log(state)  ?

Comment: Are there any other actions about bookmarks? Like delete bookmark or something that could impact on state

Comment: And also what happen in selectBookmarksProducts?

Comment: I add an initialState = { bookmarks : [ ] } and I select the bookmarks array with a selector  export const selectBookmarksProducts = createSelector(
  [selectItems],
  (shop) => shop.bookmarks
);    export const selectItems = (state) => state.products;

Comment: Is shop.bookmarks object or array?

Comment: Yes An object when I tried to log the state I thing  here is the problem because the object is not iterable